# Inserting a value in Multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, phplot

I am currently dealing with phplot, in which I want to add a line graph with several lines.

So here's the problem, let's say I have an array of data:

```
$graph->SetDataType('data-data');
$data = array(
     array("",0,37.0023239,34.4618,31.92128),
     array("",1,39.6116079,37.2759,34.94019),
     array("",2,41.4738623,39.1285,36.78314)
);
```

And now I have another array, let's call it a, where the key is actually where I want to put it inside the data array:

```
$a = array (
    "0"=>'38';
    "2"=>'40';
)
```

I wanted the data to insert them into the corresponding x value. So in the end, I want something like:

```
$data = array(
     array("",0,37.0023239,34.4618,31.92128,38),
     array("",1,39.6116079,37.2759,34.94019,''),
     array("",2,41.4738623,39.1285,36.78314,40)
);
```

Is it possible to do this? Any suggestion will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the original structure of `$data`? This would be very much easier if you initially created those sub-arrays using that `0` or `2` value as the array key. (It is here anyway, but not explicitly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost the same as the previous answer, but turning the lookup inside-out: Iterate the data array and check for each key-value pair whether `$a` contains a corresponding element; yes:append it, no:append an empty string.

```
<?php
$data = array(
     array("",0,37.0023239,34.4618,31.92128),
     array("",1,39.6116079,37.2759,34.94019),
     array("",2,41.4738623,39.1285,36.78314)
);

$a = array (
    "0"=>'38',
    "2"=>'40',
);

foreach($data as $k=>&$v) {
    $v[] = isset($a[$k]) ?  $a[$k] : '';
}

var_export($data);
```

prints

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '',
    1 => 0,
    2 => 37.0023239,
    3 => 34.461799999999997,
    4 => 31.921279999999999,
    5 => '38',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '',
    1 => 1,
    2 => 39.611607900000003,
    3 => 37.2759,
    4 => 34.940190000000001,
    5 => '',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '',
    1 => 2,
    2 => 41.4738623,
    3 => 39.128500000000003,
    4 => 36.783140000000003,
    5 => '40',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be fairly simple:

```
foreach($data as $key => &$val) {
    if(isset($a[$key])) {
        $val[] = $a[$key];
    } else {
        $val[] = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: But you forgot to add a empty value for key 1 !

Comment: Hmmm... missed that :-(

Comment: This assumes that `$data[$key]` is truly always consistent with the second value of that sub-array. It _appears_ to be that way, but maybe not.

Comment: @AbraCadaver  yeah, how about the empty value for key 1?